# Scanner - NoSuchElementException on console menu application

Tags: java

I'm making some tests with Java to work out a menu-driven console application.

I have this code:

```
    public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int option = 99;

        do{
            System.out.println("1. one");
            System.out.println("2. two");
            System.out.println("3. three");
            System.out.println("0. END");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("option : ");

            option=Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
            scan.close();
            switch (option) {
                case 0 :
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    caseOne();
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    caseTwo();
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    caseThree();
                    break;
                default :
                    break;

            }


        } while (option!=0);


    }

    private static void caseOne(){
        System.out.println("Case ONE");
    }

    private static void caseTwo(){
        System.out.println("Case TWO");
    }

    private static void caseThree(){
        System.out.println("Case THREE");
    }
}
```

When I run it it works pretty well.
I choose one option and it prints out "CASE X".

The strange behaviour is when the DO loop starts over.
It shows once again the menu but program immediatly terminates showing a NoSuchElementException  exception.
The strange thing is that it neither waits for me to enter a digit.

If a remove the

```
scan.close();
```

statement it do works fine altough compiler warns me of memory leak since scan is never closed.

It behaves very strange because on the "first pass" everything is ok even with te scan.close() but on the "second pass" it crashes even if I'm creating a new Scanner object so I think it shoul at least ask for the input.

I really get confused with this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: because you closes the stream by doing  `scan.close()` it will not able to read further.Solution is to move the statement outside loop when you finished reading.

Comment: Put `scan.close();` at the end of the method and `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` before the `do` statement

Comment: There's no reason to close a Scanner that is reading from `System.in`. You can ignore the IDE warning or do as @TheLostMind says.

Comment: thanks everybody... actually I was WRONG thinking than when I do again a NEW Scanner, on the second loop, it will re-open the stream so I can read again from it... but the scanner object wasn't destroyed so a new instance of it is no effect and remained close.

Answer (score 0):

if you are closing `scanner` it will close wrapped `input stream` also so you can close scan after finishing all of your work.

```
scan.close();
```

put it after `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

here the better way you can achieve it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int option = 99;

    do{
        System.out.println("1. one");
        System.out.println("2. two");
        System.out.println("3. three");
        System.out.println("0. END");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("option : ");

        option= scan.nextInt();
        switch (option) {
            case 0 :
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 1 :
                caseOne();
                break;
            case 2 :
                caseTwo();
                break;
            case 3 :
                caseThree();
                break;
            default :
                scan.close();
                break;

        }


    } while (option!=0);


}
```

Comment: ...but if I do this way if the user types accidentally a non-supported option it would close the stream unwillingly...

Comment: @metalredstar certainly but default is used to end up any argument and upvote it if you considered it as answer which helped you